# Manipulate <button> content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hoping someone can tell me how stupid I am in not seeing a solution to this:

I'm using jquery to manipulate the contents of buttons in accordance with their class names. I have successfully manipulated the contents for two of the cases—one in which there is no class name, the other in which the class name is "watched" as opposed to "unwatched" as in the case below.

I'm thinking it's worth mentioning that the cases of "watched" and "unwatched" are ultimately nested within the same `div`.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6 movie"><img src="">
    <div class="movie-data">
        <h4 class="movie-title">Title</h4>
        <a href="">Discover &xrarr;</a>
        <button class="unwatch" type="button"><span>Add to watchlist</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  if ($('.movie-data button').hasClass('watch')) {
    $('button > span').text('Mark as watched');
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('unwatch')) {
    $('button > span').text('S my D');
  } else {
    $('button > span').text('Add to watchlist');
  }
});
```

What I end up with is the same content for both the "watched" and "unwatched" buttons.

Comment: what `$(this)` refer to??

Comment: `'.movie-data button'`?

Comment: `$(this).hasClass('unwatch')` should be `$('.movie-data button').hasClass('unwatch')`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I've tried that already.

Comment: @AronHøyer  Have you? Because doing that gives the logically expected results. If you want to do this for more than one element you need to use `$('.movie-data button').each(function(){...})`.

Comment: I have. But not to worry. @DanielBeck had the solution, which was that an if-statement was the wrong thing to use in this regard. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing more work here than you need to.  Since you're changing things based on the presence of 'watch' or 'unwatch' classes, you can just use those as part of the selector:

```
$(function(){
  $('.movie-data button > span').text('Add to watchlist');
  $('.movie-data button.watch > span').text('Mark as watched');
  $('.movie-data button.unwatch > span').text('S my D');
});
```

(For what it's worth, though, the problems in the original code were that `$(this)` didn't point to anything useful in the context where you were using it, and each use of `$('button > span')` would match *every* button in the document, not just the ones from the containing `if` clauses.)

Comment: Yessss! Thought I was being smart with my fancy if-statement. Thank you, good sir.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

In your script `$(this)` does not refer to anything so you can check the class as you checked in the first `if` condition

```
$(function(){
    if ($('.movie-data button').hasClass('watch')) {
        $('button > span').text('Mark as watched');
    } else if ($('.movie-data button').hasClass('unwatch')) {
        $('button > span').text('S my D');
    } else {
        $('button > span').text('Add to watchlist');
    }
});
```